# String rendering method

Tags: ruby, string

If I put the below code in .rb file

```
@expression_display = "Hi hello my name is <code>man</code>"
```

And in html.erb,

```
<%= @expression_display %>
```

But the display looks just like

```
Hi hello my name is <code>man</code>
```

, not the one with "man" part highlighted.

If I just put this sentence in html file, the "man" part will be highlighted because this part followed the code command.

How can I make this properly :) ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Rails, you can use `html_safe` like this:

```
<%= @expression_display.html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<%= raw(@expression_display) %>`

`raw` doesn't escape the string. see the doc [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/RawOutputHelper/raw)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Mind if I ask a similar question to you? I get the data from what other people inserted via "textarea". They must have clicked "enter" a couple of times. I stored this data at @input as a string. But if I display it as <%=@input%> , then all sentences are messed up :(, looking the enter is not recognized as an "enter". Do you have any suggestion that I can display as the way that input users wanted to display? :)

Comment: @SungpahLee If you have any other questions, ask them in a separate thread.